# How do I calculate the length of these lines?

Tags: geometry

How do I calculate the lenght of AF and FC if lengths of AB and AD are known?
[image]

Comment: Is that a rectangle??

Comment: What else is known in the figure?

Comment: Well, yes, it is a rectangle as you can see, I mentioned that lines AB (DC) and AD (BC) have their lengths (for example AB = 4 cm and AD = 2 cm) so you can calculate the length of A.

Comment: Is there any more information? As it is, there is no way to get a unique answer. Is $F$ possibly the midpoint of $BC$?

Comment: No, the only things I know are the lengths of AB and AD, F isn't mentioned.

Comment: Well, think about it for a minute. If you don't know anything more about $F$, it could be anywhere on that line segment, right? So the lengths you are asking for, there are infinitely many different possibilities, depending on just where $F$ is, right?

Comment: Right, the reason I asked this was because our physics teacher asked us to calculate the length of AF and we only had AB and AD.For some reason she told us to extend the triangle ABF and then we would get a isosceles triangle.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "extend the triangle ABF", and I don't see any way to get an isosceles triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a rectangle than you can use Pythagorean theorem that in a right angled triangle ABC $AB^2 +BC^2 =AC^2$

similarly ABF is a right angled triangle you can again use the above theorem.

Comment: Yes, true but there's 1 problem, I don't know the lengths of BF and AF...

Comment: Is F the mid point or it divides BC in some ratio. If yes than you can still apply the above theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$AB^{2} + BC^{2} = AC^{2}$ and $DC^{2} + AD^{2} = AC^{2}$

Also you have that $AF^{2} = FB^{2} + AB^{2} =  FB^2+ DC^2$

Answer (score 0):

If you are given more information about F (such as F is the midpoint) you may simply use pythagoras to find AF since BF would be 1/2.BC